# Проблема с программой на питон

Tags: python

Имеется программа развития жизни клеток на поле,никак не пойму как организовать смерть клетки,по условию задачи клетка должна умирать через 10 секунд
Сама программа:

```
import pygame, sys 
from pygame.locals import * 
import random 

FPS = 2 #На нем висит скорость развития колонии 

WINDOWWIDTH = 600 #ширина окна, влияет на количество клеток в ширину 
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600 #высота окна, влияет на количество клеток в высоту 
CELLSIZE = 20 #размер клетки 
assert WINDOWWIDTH % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window width must be a multiple of cell size" 
assert WINDOWHEIGHT % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window height must be a multiple of cell size" 

CELLWIDTH = WINDOWWIDTH // CELLSIZE #получаем int количесвта клеток, чтобы поровну распределить на площади 
CELLHEIGHT = WINDOWHEIGHT // CELLSIZE 

#определяем цвета в RGB, можно менять 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0) 
WHITE = (255,255,255) 
DARKGRAY = (40, 40, 40) 
GREEN = (0, 255,0) 

#Отрисовка решетки 
def Grider(): 
for x in range(0, WINDOWWIDTH, CELLSIZE): 
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x,0),(x,WINDOWHEIGHT)) 
for y in range (0, WINDOWHEIGHT, CELLSIZE): 
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (0,y), (WINDOWWIDTH, y)) 

#заполняем клетки 
def kletki(): 
grid = {} 
for y in range (CELLHEIGHT): 
for x in range (CELLWIDTH): 
grid[x,y] = 0 
return grid 

#а теперь заполняем их рандомной жизнью 
def RandomFill(life): 
for item in life:  
life[item] = random.randint(0,1) 
return life 

#красим живых в зеленый 
def colourise(item, life): 
x = item[0] 
y = item[1] 
y = y * CELLSIZE 
x = x * CELLSIZE 
if life[item] == 0: 
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, (x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)) 
if life[item] == 1: 
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)) 
return None 

#получаем информацию о соседях клетки 
def Neighbour(item,life): 
neighbours = 0 
for x in range (-1,2): 
for y in range (-1,2): 
checkCell = (item[0]+x,item[1]+y) 
if checkCell[0] < CELLWIDTH and checkCell[0] >=0: 
if checkCell [1] < CELLHEIGHT and checkCell[1]>= 0: 
if life[checkCell] == 1: 
if x == 0 and y == 0: 
neighbours += 0 
else: 
neighbours += 1 
return neighbours 

#высчитываем потенциал клетки, можно менять абсолютно все ради динамики, 
#не стал делать смерть от 6 клеток соседей, так как в таком случае колония не двигается 
def tick(life): 
newTick = {} 
for item in life: 
numberNeighbours = Neighbour(item, life) 
if life[item] == 1: 
if numberNeighbours < 2: 
newTick[item] = 0 
elif numberNeighbours > 2: 
newTick[item] = 0 
else: 
newTick[item] = 1 
elif life[item] == 0: 
if numberNeighbours == 2: 
newTick[item] = 1 
else: 
newTick[item] = 0 
return newTick 

#главная функция, отрисовка всего и обновление экрана для дальнейшей отрисовки 
def main(): 
pygame.init() 
global DISPLAYSURF 
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock() 
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('Life') 
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE) 
life = kletki() 
life = RandomFill(life) 
for item in life: 
colourise(item, life) 
Grider() 
pygame.display.update() 

while True: #вот здесь главный цикл, время и распределение цвета 
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
if event.type == QUIT: 
pygame.quit() 
sys.exit() 
life = tick(life) 
for item in life: 
colourise(item, life) 
Grider() 
pygame.display.update() 
FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS) 

if __name__=='__main__': 
main()
```

Comment: У вас в коде вся идентация (отступы) пропали. Без правки кода разобраться не получится

Comment: Вставьте код в вопрос как есть, потом добавьте выше и ниже кода строки с тремя косыми апострофами \`\`\`

Comment: Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, используйте [кнопку править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1143040/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Поправил я ваш код и разобрался в нём.
Теперь клетка хранит не только жива она или нет, но и время её создания, всё это в виде списка в виде `[0, time.time()]`, так же дополнил функцией, которая вызывается когда клетка и до этого была жива и осталась жить, функция просто смотрит, если клетка жила больше 10 сек возвращает True и клетка убивается, хотя в иных условиях осталась бы жить.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import time

FPS = 2 #На нем висит скорость развития колонии

WINDOWWIDTH = 600 #ширина окна, влияет на количество клеток в ширину
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600 #высота окна, влияет на количество клеток в высоту
CELLSIZE = 20 #размер клетки
assert WINDOWWIDTH % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window width must be a multiple of cell size"
assert WINDOWHEIGHT % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window height must be a multiple of cell size"

CELLWIDTH = WINDOWWIDTH // CELLSIZE #получаем int количесвта клеток, чтобы поровну распределить на площади
CELLHEIGHT = WINDOWHEIGHT // CELLSIZE

#определяем цвета в RGB, можно менять
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
DARKGRAY = (40, 40, 40)
GREEN = (0, 255,0)

#Отрисовка решетки
def Grider():
    for x in range(0, WINDOWWIDTH, CELLSIZE):
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x,0),(x,WINDOWHEIGHT))
    for y in range (0, WINDOWHEIGHT, CELLSIZE):
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (0,y), (WINDOWWIDTH, y))

#заполняем клетки
def kletki():
    grid = {}
    for y in range (CELLHEIGHT):
        for x in range (CELLWIDTH):
            grid[x,y] = [0, time.time()]
    return grid

#а теперь заполняем их рандомной жизнью
def RandomFill(life):
    for item in life:
        life[item][0] = random.randint(0,1)
        life[item][1] = time.time()
    return life

#красим живых в зеленый
def colourise(item, life):
    x = item[0]
    y = item[1]
    y = y * CELLSIZE
    x = x * CELLSIZE
    if life[item][0] == 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, (x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE))
    if life[item][0] == 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE))
    return None

#получаем информацию о соседях клетки
def Neighbour(item,life):
    neighbours = 0
    for x in range (-1,2):
        for y in range (-1,2):
            checkCell = (item[0]+x,item[1]+y)
            if checkCell[0] < CELLWIDTH and checkCell[0] >=0:
                if checkCell [1] < CELLHEIGHT and checkCell[1]>= 0:
                    if life[checkCell][0] == 1:
                        if x == 0 and y == 0:
                            neighbours += 0
                        else:
                            neighbours += 1
    return neighbours

#высчитываем потенциал клетки, можно менять абсолютно все ради динамики,
#не стал делать смерть от 6 клеток соседей, так как в таком случае колония не двигается
def tick(life):
    newTick = {}
    for item in life:
        numberNeighbours = Neighbour(item, life)
        if life[item][0] == 1:
            if numberNeighbours < 2:
                newTick[item] = [0,0]
            elif numberNeighbours > 2:
                newTick[item] = [0,0]
            else:
                #Здесь проверяется, если клетка жила больше 10 секунд, мы её убиваем, и ставим время
                # но оно не на что не виляет, так как клетка мертва, Если прошло больше 10 сек, то оставляем её время создания
                if oldCheck(life[item]):
                    newTick[item] = [0, 0]
                else:
                    newTick[item] = [1, life[item][1]]


        elif life[item][0] == 0:
            if numberNeighbours == 2:
                newTick[item] = [1,time.time()]
            else:
                newTick[item] = [0,0]

    return newTick

def oldCheck(cell):
    if cell[1] > time.time() + 10:
        return  True


#главная функция, отрисовка всего и обновление экрана для дальнейшей отрисовки
def main():
    pygame.init()

    global DISPLAYSURF
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Life')
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    life = kletki()
    life = RandomFill(life)

    for item in life:
        colourise(item, life)
    Grider()
    pygame.display.update()



    while True: #вот здесь главный цикл, время и распределение цвета
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        life = tick(life)

        for item in life:
            colourise(item, life)
        Grider()

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А вообще, если интересует, у меня есть своя версия написанной этой программы на гитхабе, тоже на основе pygame

Comment: интересует!.....